# How do I access nested list in raket using car cdr caar caddr etc.?

Tags: list, nested, racket

I am trying to get familiar with accessing the nested list in Racket. I have the following problem. For example I have  a list like this `define x (list 1 2 3 )` I understand that `(car x) -> 1`  and `(cdr x) -> (2 3)`. But if I have a list like this define `y (list (list (list 6 7 8 ) 2 5 ) 3 4 5 6 ))` and I run `(caaar y)` I get `6`. I understand what is happening until now. What I am not understanding is why do I get an error when I run `(caadr y)`. (saying contract violation)  instead of returning `( 7 8 )`.  Can you explain this to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(caadr y)` is `(car (car (cdr y)))`, so you will get `(car (car '(3 4 5 6)))` => `(car 3)`=> `error`.

You need to return `'(7 8)`, that is `(cdr (car (car y)))`, so letters are taken in this order: `C-cDr-cAr-cAr-R => CDAAR, (cdaar y)`.